# Why is this use of count() not valid in php?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

There are a bunch of questions relating to errors with the `count()` logic in some phpmyadmin libraries but they all seem slightly different to this one.

I'm at a bit of a loss with this strange behavior in the 'Designer' tab. I'm informed that **'errors have been detected on the server!'** and that I should **'look at the bottom of this window'**, but as you can see from the image there is nothing in the console and the error message is obscured:

[image: screendump1]

After getting this popup every time I opened the Designer tab, I decided to track it down:

[image]

... and looking at the line in question, #405, in **/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/pmd_common.php**, I found:

```php
if (count($min_page_no[0])) {
```

... but isn't this a perfectly legal use of the `count()` function?
This is in a library file so how can I debug this? - I tried to `var_dump($min_page_no[0]);` and reload the page to see what I'm dealing with, but nothing was displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your installation of phpMyAdmin.

I believe 4.7.8 addresses this, as evidenced by the release tag on this commit:

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/c77cfa7d13370a7f1e3236c5896f89981e61406f

[Edit: And an explanation of why count isn't valid in this case: That particular index isn't always set. If they try to use `count()` on an array index that isn't set, it'll throw that warning.]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Interestingly when I change the line to `if (isset($min_page_no[0]) && count($min_page_no[0])) {` as suggested in the link you provided I still get the popup error message but not the hidden message box. However, changing it to `if (count((array)$min_page_no[0])) {` seems to get rid of both.

Comment: To be completely honest, you really should just update the entire library. There's literally thousands of updates since the version you are currently using was released.

Comment: The problem with updating is that when I run `apt-cache policy phpmyadmin` I get: 

`phpmyadmin:
  Installed: 4:4.6.6-5
  Candidate: 4:4.6.6-5
  Version table:
 *** 4:4.6.6-5 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

which means the latest version isn't available in the ppa yet.

Comment: Oh, I see. You have my sympathies. That version is _astoundingly_ old. Well if you're fine with manually patching, many fixes (or nudges toward a fix) for these sorts of PHP warnings can be found in the commits. [A manual install is also an option if you find you're running into lots of issues.]

Comment: You can remove the packaged version and install your own (https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#quick-install), using the phpMyAdmin PPA package (https://launchpad.net/~phpmyadmin/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), or several other methods (such as Docker) in order to run a more up-to-date version of phpMyAdmin. You might have luck filing a bug report directly with Ubuntu (since it's their packaged version that is unfixed), but it's unlikely they'll patch this. Besides, 4.6.6 is over three years old at this point, I agree that you should update.